# Raise click event on an element from another template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I made a view for saving and showing models. It has events like this,

```
events: -> 
  "click li": "addEntry" 
  "click .remove": "destroyEntry" 

addEntry: (e) -> 
  movie_title = $(e.target).text()
  @collection.create title: movie_title

appendEntry: (entry) ->
  view = new Movieseat.Views.Entry(model: entry)
  $('#entries').append(view.render().el)

destroyEntry: (e) -> 
  thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).closest('div').data('id')
  @collection.get(thisid).destroy()
```

Now if I put a li element in the template and I click on it the `addEntry` event gets triggerd and saves the model to my Rails database. Also my `destroyEntry` event works to remove the models. And the `appendEntry` function gets triggered when a model gets added to the collection.

But I'm using a different view to show a collection of movies in a list. Now I want to connect the click li event to a li on a different template. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In your other view, you can use the same source of data. In this case it is the collection of movies. Since it's backbone, and the views are really just a representation of the data models, use the data to render or trigger changes in the views.

In the other view, watch the changes on the collection that is being manipulated. No need to delegate events when all you really care about is the data being changed.

```
OtherView = Backbone.View.extend
  initialize: (params) ->
    # this could also be the model, I'm not sure how you have this configured
    @listenTo params.movieseats, "change", @updateMovies

  updateMovies: ->
    # manage the view here
```

Comment: Makes sence, but how do I referende to the other collection? If I use `addEntry: (e) -> 
    movie_title = $(e.target).text()
    @collection.create title: movie_title` in my other view the code selects the wrong collection which results in a error `OPTIONS http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=star  
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=star. Invalid HTTP status code 404 `